# MySQL - How do I change the format of a date which is using the mediumtext data type?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqldatatypes

How do I change the format of a date which is using the mediumtext data type? I can't find a solution anywhere.

From:

```
+-------------+----------------------------+
|  Page Name  | Last Modified (mediumtext) |
+-------------+----------------------------+
| Page Name 1 | Jul 20, 2018 16:06         |
| Page Name 2 | Jun 04, 2019 11:16         |
| Page Name 3 | Sep 03, 2019 13:11         |
| Page Name 4 | Sep 19, 2019 14:00         |
| Page Name 5 | Dec 20, 2019 09:34         |
+-------------+----------------------------+
```

To:

```
+-------------+----------------------+
|  Page Name  | Last Modified (date) |
+-------------+----------------------+
| Page Name 1 | 2018-07-20           |
| Page Name 2 | 2019-06-04           |
| Page Name 3 | 2019-09-03           |
| Page Name 4 | 2019-09-19           |
| Page Name 5 | 2019-12-20           |
+-------------+----------------------+
```

Select Statement:

```
Select PageName, LastModDate from Content
```

I have tried using the below code but they return Null.

```
- CONVERT(LastModDat, DATETIME)
- DATE_FORMAT(LastModDat, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str_to_date()` in MySQL:

```
select str_to_date(left(last_modified, 13), '%M %d, %Y')
```

This produces a `date` value.  I do NOT recommend converting this to a string.